# Are there any safer options than `sudo sync && halt -n` for troubled states?

Tags: reboot, macos

I find that two of my macOS workstations have hang from time to time. They aren't resolved even by `sudo reboot` or `su; reboot`. In these cases `sudo sync && halt -n` usually does the trick and this of course is slightly safer than just holding the power button.

Are there any other "safer" ways to harshly force a system down when something prevents a proper reboot?

Comment: What do you mean my hung? I see that you can type commands. What else can you do? and what can you not do?

Comment: In this case it only allows ssh in. Window Manager et al is hung.

Comment: I have had problems in the past of X11-windowing systems hanging. Usually a dodgy app. I could resolve it by re-booting the windowing system (ctrl-alt-backspace if configured). I don't know if you can reboot the windowing system on mac. [on Microsoft's Windows I would not be surprised if you could reboot just the OS while leaving the Windowing system running.]

Comment: Yeah unfortunately there's no reasonable way to do that and since xnu is a little more crufty depending on kexts it's got loaded, it's alright to just reboot entirely.